# How to add up values of the "sublists" within a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a list of lists in my script:

```
list = [[1,2]
        [4,3]
        [6,2]
        [1,6]
        [9,2]
        [6,5]]
```

I am looking for a solution to sum up the contents of each "sublist" within the list of lists. The desired output would be:

```
new_list = [3,7,8,7,11,11]
```

I know about combining ALL of these lists into one which would be:

```
new_list = [27,20]
```

But that's not what i'm looking to accomplish.
I need to combine the two values within these "sublists" and have them remain as their own entry in the main list.

I would also greatly appreciate it if it was also explained *how* you solved the problem rather than just handing me the solution. I'm trying to learn python so even a minor explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Using Python 3.7.4

Thanks, Riftie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "manual" solution will be using a for loop.

```py
new_list = []
for sub_list in list:
   new_list.append(sum(sub_list))
```

or as list compherension:

```py
new_list = [sum(sub_list) for sub_list in list]
```

The for loop iterates through the elements of list. In your case, `list` is a list of lists. So every element is a list byitself. That means that while iterating, sub_list is a simple list. To get a sum of list I used `sum()` build-in function. You can of course iterate manually and sum every element:

```py
new_list = []
for sub_list in list:
   sum_val = 0
   for element in sub_list:
       sum_val = sum_val + element
   new_list.append(sum_val)
```

but no need for that.

A better approach will be to use `numpy`, which allows you to sum by axis, as it looks on list of lists like an array. Since you are learning basic python, it's too soon to learn about numpy. Just keep in mind that there is a package for handling multi-dimensions arrays and it allows it perform some actions like sum on an axis by your choice.

Edit: I've seen the other solution suggest. As both will work, I believe this solution is more "accessible" for someone who learn to program for first time. Using list comprehension is great and correct, but may be a bit confusing while first learning. Also as suggested, calling your variables `list` is a bad idea because it's keyword. Better names will be "my_list", "tmp_list" or something else.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution(s) and explanation. Also I was just using "list" as an example. It's not written that way in my script. Nonetheless, thank you for the insight and input.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension. Also avoid using keywords as variable names, in your case you overrode the builtin `list`.

```
# a, b -> sequence unpacking
summed = [a + b for a, b in lst] # where lst is your list of lists

# if the inner lists contain variable number of elements, a more 
# concise solution would be
summed2 = [sum(seq) for seq in lst]
```

Read more about the powerful list comprehension [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).